# Convert TensorFlow Tensor into numpy before assigning values to neural net

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I am working with the [DCGAN code](https://github.com/carpedm20/DCGAN-tensorflow). I need to modify [the reward](https://github.com/carpedm20/DCGAN-tensorflow/blob/master/model.py#L127) that is given to one of the neural nets by adding a function that would take the output of this neural net, analyse it, and issue a penalty on it. So my loss function would look like:

```
self.g_loss = self.g_loss + self.penalty
```

Problem is

- this penalty function only takes the numpy arrays as an input (I have no way of modifying this),
- neural network output is a tf.tensor,
- and as the values haven't been assigned to the neural net yet (technically it hasn't been built yet) I can't run neither `.eval()` nor `sess.run()`.

So how would I convert a tensorflow tensor into numpy array in this case?

Comment: If you expect to train your neural network you'll need to also provide a gradient for your penalty. If you do have it, you probably need to add a custom op to tensorflow to take care of this...

Answer (score 2):

Tensorflow has `tf.py_func` for [wrapping Python functions and passing tensors to them](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/py_func). However, you can't then use this loss function to train the network, because Tensorflow doesn't automatically differentiate numpy code.

Luckily for you, [autograd *does* automatically differentiate numpy code](https://github.com/HIPS/autograd). If you use that, in another `tf.pyfunc` call, you can get gradients, which you can then [put back into the tensorflow graph on the backward pass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38833934/write-custom-python-based-gradient-function-for-an-operation-without-c-imple).

Here's an example of how you can do it all in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/gngdb/aa0766293b1e689d06fbde8d430a014c).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Currently I am using `g_optim = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(config.learning_rate, beta1=config.beta1) \
              .minimize(self.g_loss, var_list=self.g_vars)` as my optimiser. How would I keep that for all (or at least tf part of) my loss?

Comment: Also running the tf-autograd.py throws the following error: `InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): 0-th value returned by pyfunc_1 is double, but expects float
  [[Node: PyFunc_1 = PyFunc[Tin=[DT_DOUBLE], Tout=[DT_FLOAT], token="pyfunc_1", _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](Variable/read/_3)]]
`.

Comment: Are you running this on gpu? In that case Tensorflow defaults to float32, while numpy is default float64.

Comment: Yes, I run on GPU, how do I fix this discrepancy?

Comment: I've updated the gist so it'll work on a system with gpus, but the only way I could get it to work was by enforcing `float32` and `cpu` device usage almost everywhere.